# NSObject's initialize() not called in Release build configuration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa

According to Apple documentation `initialize()` method Initializes the class before it receives its first message.

Can somebody explain why initialize() is not working in Release build configuration?

For example:

```
class Test: NSObject {
    override class func initialize() {
        print("initialize")
    }
    class func test() {
        print("test")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Test.test()
    }
}
```

Output in Debug configuration:

```
initialize
test
```

Output in Release configuration:

```
test
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick test and it looks like in `Release` configuration `+ initialize` is not called unless you create an instance of the class. However in `Debug` calling a class method is enough to trigger `+initialize`. Looks like an undocumented caveat.

Edit:
Even more interesting fact is that for Objective-C project in both `Debug` and `Release` configurations calling a class method is enough to trigger `+ initialize`. I would say this is a bug. You might want to file a radar for it.

Comment: The specific setting appears to be the Swift Compiler - Code Generation / Optimization level. 'None [-Onone] versus 'Fast, Single-File Optimization [-O]'